# Loop Through Formset To Sum Values - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Django Form Set where each form has an amount with class = `amount2`.  Each time a change is made to any one of these inputs with that class I would like to re-total the value of all inputs with class `amount2`.  Currently I am trying this

```
$('.amount2').on("input", function() {
  var sum = 0
  $('.amount2').each(function() {
    sum += $(this).val();
    console.log(sum)
  })
})
```

when I log `sum` I get 0 despite the fact that I am entering 5 in the input. So I tried to dial it back a bit and do this

```
$('.amount2').on("input", function() {
  var sum = 0
  $('.amount2').each(function() {
    sum += 10;
    console.log(sum)
  })
})
```

That log returns prints the number 10 as I would expect when I make one input and 20 on the next.

So what is going wrong with my first bit?

**UPDATED**

```
  {% for form in formset.forms %}
                <table id = 'manifest-table25' class="manifest-table2" width=100%>
                  {% csrf_token %}
                  <tbody width=100%>
                    <tr class="manifest-row">
                      <td width = 17.5% class="productCode" onchange="populateProduct(this)">{{form.ProductCode}}</td>
                      <td width = 32.5% class="description">{{form.DescriptionOfGoods}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="quantity" oninput="calculateUnit(this)">{{form.UnitQty}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="unitType">{{form.Type}}</td>
                      <td width = 10.5% class="price" oninput="calculate(this)">{{form.Price}}</td>
                      <td width = 12.5% class="amount2">{{form.Amount}}</td>
                      {% with url_name=request.resolver_match.url_name %}
                      {% if url_name == 'EditQuoteView' %}
                        <td>{{form.DELETE}}</td>

                      {% endif %}
                      {% endwith %}
                      {{form.id}}
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              {% endfor %}
```

Comment: What type for html elements exactly are the `.amount2`?  An example of the html would be helpful.

Comment: In order to eliminate one possibility, I would try something as simple as `sum += Number($(this).val())`. Just to rule out the possibility of it not being typecasted

Comment: That's very good debugging, but the difference in results you describe doesn't add up (no pun intended... ok, maybe a little). Are you sure the first code is representative of your actual code?

Comment: @slappy yes it was copied and pasted - I tried the answers below but they still seem to not work.  The input is for an integer. I tried ```sum += Number($(this).val())``` but it still returned 0.

Comment: I've added a snip of the html above.

Comment: `.amount2` is not an `input` element, it's a `td`. The `.val()` method is for inputs, but unfortunately, jQuery returns an empty string even when running `.val()` on non-input elements instead of returning something that would give a more meaningful distinction, like `undefined`. So you can use `.text()` instead, or better, ditch jQuery and use the native API to get the values you need.

Comment: ...if there's an `input` nested in the `td`, the you need to select that descendant of the `td` and use `.val()`.

Answer (score 2):

Input, textarea, select, or contenteditable *value* is **always a String**. (Even if the InputElement has the HTML attribute `type="number"`). Remember to always handle conversion before doing math.

Use `parseInt(val, 10)`, `parseFloat(val)`,  `Number(val)`, or `BigInt(val)` etc. to convert a string to Integer, Float or Number

```js
const $amount2 = $('.amount2');

$amount2.on("input", function() {
  let sum = 0
  $amount2.each(function() {
    sum += Number(this.value);
  });
  $("#amount2-sum").text(sum);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="amount2">
<input type="number" class="amount2">
<div id="amount2-sum"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Additionally for fun you could use jQuery's `.get()`, JS's `.Array.prototype.reduce()` and the unary `+` to coerce a String to Number

```js
const $amount2 = $('.amount2');

$amount2.on("input", function() {
  const sum = $amount2.get().reduce((sum, el) => sum + +el.value, 0);
  $("#amount2-sum").text(sum);
});
```

```html
<input type="number" class="amount2">
<input type="number" class="amount2">
<div id="amount2-sum"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If this were the actual issue, wouldn't the user see `5555`, instead of 0 as a result?

Comment: `var x = 0; x += '5';` in the console is "05", instead of 0, as the user says the result is for the first snippet.  So something is missing in their explaination of the issue.

Comment: yes @Taplar But the only issue I see in OP's code is the way he handles String vs numbers. You might be right though, some issue in another part of the app, or OP just missed to put it into words - Therefore the above's code and examples

Comment: Your `.reduce` callback can simply be `(sum, el) => sum += +el.value`... The `, sum` doesn't alter the return value

Comment: @slappy thank you very much, finger memory can be hard at times :)

Comment: My pleasure, and might as well make the `+=` into a `+`, so that you're not needlessly mutating the parameter. Helps with clarity a little bit too.